# ASP.NET Treeview control default behavior

Tags: asp.net, html, servercontrols

I have a page using a Treeview server control like so:

```
<asp:TreeView ID="uxTreeView" ShowExpandCollapse="True" ShowCheckBoxes="All" runat="server"></asp:TreeView>
```

What I *expect* to have happen is my treeview should render a series of checkboxes, with the first level having a plus sign (+) to expand it, and then a minus sign (-) when it's expanded to collapse it.

For some reason, I'm not seeing the expand/collapse links. I can see there's a parent and a child node, and they're properly nested, but the expand/collapse links aren't showing.

Has anyone seen this before? In the past this hasn't been an issue - dragging and dropping the control onto a page has worked fine. I've inspected the elements with Firebug, and I didn't see any CSS that would hide the expand/collapse links.

**UPDATE**

I've found there's an ImageSet property on the treeview - now my treeview is actually adding the arrows for the various nodes indicating whether they're expanded or collapsed. Is it possible to style the individual cells in the outputted table? (It looks like this would be a lot of work)

Comment: The expand/collapse icons are actually images. Check that nothing is interfering with WebResource.axd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you by chance specify custom images, perhaps incorrectly, for the expand and collapse elements?

Comment: No, I've got no images set for the expand and collapse elements. I'm using the default properties.

Comment: The strange thing is the default behavior doesn't work...but when I specify an ImageSet, the control renders fine.